# Ошибка при запуске нескольких процессов

Tags: python, многопоточность

Начал разбираться с потоками. Для этого написал следующий код:

```
def sqrt_pandas(x,q):
    q.put(math.sqrt(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print(n_proc)
    process = []
    lst_proc = []
    number = 0
    lst = [random.randint(1, 10000) for i in range(0, 1000)]

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in lst:
        if number<n_proc:
            q = multiprocessing.Queue()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=sqrt_pandas, args=(i, q))
            process.append(p)
            p.start()
            print(q.get())
        else:
            for p in process:
                p.join()
            process = []
            number = 0

    print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pycharm_project_880/test.py", line 27, in <module>
p.start()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
self._launch(process_obj)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 69, in _launch
child_r, parent_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

В чем я ошибся при написании данного кода.

Comment: Да вроде всё работает. А что за ОС и сколько у вас в `n_proc` получается? Такое впечатление, что у вас процессы в ОС кончились.

Comment: Да, и это весь код? А то может вы до того файлов пооткрывали. В общем, почитайте этот вопрос и ответы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526783/python-subprocess-too-many-open-files

Comment: @CrazyElf - ос ubunta, а n_proc 128.

Comment: @CrazyElf да это весь код. Но вы правы процессы и правда закончились, я забыл добавить увелечение счетчика при создании процесса (number)

Comment: @CrazyElf да правда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, ну с сутью ошибки вы сами разобрались - счётчик `number` у вас не увеличивался, `join` не происходил и процессы в системе в итоге заканчивались. Но главное в вашем коде - у вас нет на самом деле никакой многопоточности, процессы выполняются последовательно! Это происходит из-за вызова `q.get()` - он ждёт результата. Поэтому следующий процесс у вас стартует не раньше, чем заканчивается предыдущий. Рекомендую вам воспользоваться классом `multiprocessing.Pool`, с ним ваш код будет гораздо короче, проще, и, что главное, эффективнее:

```py
import multiprocessing
import math
import time

def sqrt_pandas(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    lst = [random.randint(1, 10000) for i in range(0, 1000)]
    result = []

    start_time = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(n_proc) as pool:
        for res in pool.map(sqrt_pandas, lst):
            result.append(res)

    print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Печать я убрал, чтобы не забивала экран, но даже с печатью этот код выполняется за доли секунды.

Как видите, 12 строчек кода работы с процессами превратились в 3 строки, и при этом всё просто и понятно.