# BeautifulSoup и threading/multiprocessing

Tags: python, парсер, multiprocessing, threading

Мне нужно пройтись по двумерному массиву, в котором содержаться ссылки и совершить определенное действие с ссылками с этого массива через BeautifulSoup и добавить определенной элемент в тот подмассив, с которого я брал ссылку.

У меня есть готовый код, который делает эту задачу, но он работает слишком медленно и я решил его ускорить с помощью threading, однако я столкнулся с проблемами, которые не могу решить, поэтому прошу помощи у вас.

```
import bs4
import requests
import threading

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})
matches = []

def save_matches():
    try:
        r = s.get(f"https://777score.ru/31-10-2022")
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        info_chemp = soup.find_all(class_='tournaments-item')
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(info_chemp)):
            info_matches = info_chemp[i].find_all(class_='tournaments-match tournaments-game-item')
            for y in range(len(info_matches)):
                link = str(info_matches[y].find_all('a')[0].get('href').strip())
                link = link.replace(f"?mdate=31-10-2022", '')
                if "Перенесен" in str(info_matches[y]):
                    continue
                if "javascript" not in link:
                    matches.append([])
                    matches[count].append(f"https://777score.ru{link}")
                    count += 1
    except BaseException:
        pass

def save(matches, i):
    try:
        link = matches[0]
        if len(link) > 0:
            r = s.get(f"{link}/h2h")
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
            if soup.find('div', class_='error-404') is None:
                info_chemp = soup.find_all(class_="tab-content hidden")[1]
                info_chemp = info_chemp.find_all(class_="tournaments-item category-")
                matches[i].append(info_chemp)
    except BaseException:
        pass

save_matches()

for i in range(len(matches)):
    threading.Thread(target=save, args=([matches[i], i])).start()

print(matches)
```

На выходе программы я планирую получить свой двумерный массив *matches*, где будет добавлен необходимый мне элемент в подмассив моего двумерного массива, но вместо этого я получаю не измененный двумерный массив, как будто я и не запускал функцию *save*.

Возможно эту задачу лучше решить с помощью *multiprocessing*, но я перечитал много статей и так не смог реализовать эту технологию в моем коде. Если вы сможете показать мне на примере, как мне необходимо решить мою проблему с помощью *threading* или же *multiprocessing*, я вам буду очень сильно благодарен!

Comment: "У меня есть готовый код, который делает эту задачу" вы для начала разберитесь с "готовым кодом"

Comment: @СергейШ, готовый код это делает без threading или же multiprocessing, поэтому я и прошу помощи в реализации моего вопроса

Comment: "готовый код это делает без threading или же multiprocessing" А можно это код увидет?

Comment: @СергейШ, замените вторую часть кода: 
`def save():
    for i in range(len(matches)):
        link = matches[i][0]
        if len(link) > 0:
            r = s.get(f"{link}/h2h")
            soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
            if soup.find('div', class_='error-404') is None:
                info_chemp = soup.find_all(class_="tab-content hidden")[1]
                info_chemp = info_chemp.find_all(class_="tournaments-item category-")
                matches[i].append(info_chemp)
save_matches()
save()
for i in range(len(matches)):
    print(matches[i])`

Comment: 1. Злоупотребляете try-except. 2. В функций save(matches, i) параметр matches совпадает с именем вашего списка. 3. Вам в коде надо дождатся выполнения всех потоков и потом только делать print(matches).

Comment: @СергейШ, в функции save(matches, i) параметр matches изменил, но это ни на что не повлияло. print(matches) у меня ведь и так стоит в конце кода, после цикла с потоками

Comment: Вам в коде надо дождатся выполнения всех потоков и потом только делать print(matches).

Comment: @СергейШ, у меня print(matches) стоит после выполнения всех потоков.

Comment: "после выполнения всех потоков" нет, ваш код не ждет выполнения всех потоков. Видимо вы очень плохо представляете работу потоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bs4
import requests
import threading

s = requests.session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0'})

def save(link):
        r = s.get(f"{link}/h2h")
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        info_chemp = soup.find_all(class_="tab-content hidden")[1]
        info_chemp = info_chemp.find_all(class_="tournaments-item category-")
        result.append([link, info_chemp])


result =[]
matches = ['https://777score.ru/football/matches/betis-balompie-vs-real-sociedad',
           'https://777score.ru/football/matches/hoffenheim-vs-koln']
threads = []
for link in matches:
    t = threading.Thread(target=save, args=(link,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)
# ждем, когда потоки выполнятся
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это то, что мне было нужно!

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, вы можете показать пример вашего кода, только с использованием multiprocessing, а не threading? Буду очень вам благодарен!

Comment: как пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1413906/470333